# How to get constraints is ios8 before layoutSubviews?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a view that is subclass of UIView,when I add constraints in xib,and now I should get the array constraints, I tried, but it is different between iOS 7 and iOS 8.
it work for iOS 7,and iOS 8 is be invalid.

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{

   self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
   if (self) {

    NSLog(@"constraints = %@",self.constraints);
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: I don't know when in a views lifetime the constraints are added. Maybe not in initWithCoder but later on iOS8 ?

Comment: i add constraints in xib, it invoke initwithCoder when load view.

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: The array is nil when in iOS 8.

Comment: Is it nil in awakeFromNib or viewDidAppear ? I guess the precedence of setting up views has changed in iOS8 and in initWithCoder it is too early to ask for constraints.

Comment: the array count is zero in awakeFromNib method. It have values in layoutSubviews,but it's too late,I want to get this array before layoutSubviews.

Comment: This code works on iPhone 5s with iOS 8.3. I've got array of constrains. I also created view from xib file and set constrains like you. What is the device and iOS version that you use.

Comment: Oh i found that i can get constrains by this code when I load xib in code but if I set it by change the view's class in storyboard to custom class with xib it will return empty array like you.

Answer (score 0):

Is AutoLayout turned off for your xib?

If I take one of my projects, and run it on iOS8, with AutoLayout turned off, I get:

```
2015-04-29 00:30:48.796 simpletest[37423:4105842] constraints = (
)
```

If I turn AutoLayout back on, I get a list of constraints:

```
2015-04-29 00:32:03.755 simpletest[37448:4107364] constraints = (
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a694c90 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7a87f280]-(0)-[UIButton:0x7a6834a0'Another View']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a691b90 UIButton:0x7a6834a0'Another View'.leading == UIView:0x7a87ef50.leadingMargin>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a6871c0 V:[UIButton:0x7a6834a0'Another View']-(100)-[UIView:0x7a87f0f0]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a696670 UIView:0x7a87f0f0.leading == UIView:0x7a87ef50.leadingMargin + 30>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a691bf0 UIView:0x7a87ef50.trailingMargin == UIView:0x7a87f0f0.trailing + 30>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a686620 V:[UIView:0x7a87f0f0]-(100)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7a87f950]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7a68d8f0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7a87f280(0)]>",
etc.
```

The checkbox to turn AutoLayout on or off is near the bottom of this image:
[image]

---

Rereading your post, it seems that you are actually adding constraints which you can't do if you had AutoLayout turned off.  So maybe that is not your issue.  However, as you can see from my output, iOS8 doesn't return a nil for self.constraints when there are constraints.

Comment: NO,if I turn off it ,I con't add constraints.Are you sure you are printed log in initwihtCoder method?

Comment: oh,it's my fault,it's a empty array.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should consider moving your logic to awakeFromNib. This is the start point for all nibs/xibs. initWithCoder doesn't have IBOutlets loaded yet, for example.

Second, remember that when you add constraints relative to other siblings, is the parent the one that holds the constraint. So if A has a horizontal constraint to B, then the constraint will be in A.superview.constraints.

However if A has constraints not based no other views like height or width, you will find them in A.constraints.

Comment: why do you want to get the cosntraint before layoutSubviews ?

Comment: Because i want to get textview‘s original height ,then to limit textview's height when user input

Comment: then, this response I made this morning might help you. Take a look at the part where explains how to get TextVieww's to resize for content http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29936763/change-scrollview-height-based-on-content-of-the-view/29937115#29937115